# Build\Create Model of mvc5 (code-first) with a relationship of one to many (N-arry?) of FIXED number of the many elements

Tags: c#, asp.net, model, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first

it's my first question here so sorry if I am doing something wrong. I didn't find answer for it here.

I need to build my db with the following Meta-data:

```
public class Room
{
    [Key]
    public int RoomID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students {get;set;}
}

public class Student 
{
    [Key]
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Each Room can have up to 20 Student. it can be 0 students, 5 students or 20 students but not more.

How can I do it?

note: 
    I know that I can just change the line:

```
public virtual ICollection<Student> Students {get;set;}
```

to someting like this:

```
public virtual  Student Student-01 {get;set;}
public virtual  Student Student-02 {get;set;}
....
public virtual  Student Student-20 {get;set;}
```

but I am looking for more elegant solution.

I also know that I can control the Students number in the Controller of the Room create/edit action

but I would like to change only the DB (model), unless there is no other solution?

Thanks,

Comment: There are a few options. You could override SaveChanges (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716714(v=vs.100).aspx), or one of the options here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086342/constrain-the-number-of-child-entities-in-entity-framework

Comment: You need to consider that EF can only validate against data it has in memory.  The only way for it to be enforced is every time you add a student, retrieve all existing students for that Room or issue a count query.  If you have an AddStudent action, you will have to query the DB every time to check and see how many students are currently in the room.  To my knowledge, there's no way to create a DB level constraint that enforces this(an overly complicated trigger could). **I would strongly consider that this logic be in your business layer instead of part of the data model.**

Comment: I know that's not your goal though, so didn't post as an answer because I don't want to detract away from what you are trying to accomplish.  Good luck.

Comment: tnx @SteveGreene & AaronLS. If there is no other way, I will change the  business model by overriding the SaveChanges or modifying the controller of Room.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like something that could be achieved through EF's validation features:

- One thing you could try is implementing [`IValidatableObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject) on one of the classes to validate that the number of students is below the maximum limit. In the past, I would have done this from the "many" side of the relationship, but your model for `Student` doesn't seem to have a reference to its `Room`.
- Another option is overriding `DbContext.ValidateEntity`.

In either case, the validation would occur when either `DbContext.SaveChanges` or `DbContext.GetValidationErrors` is called.

For more information about Entity Framework validation, you can see [this article on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193959.aspx).

Comment: I do acknowledge what @AaronLS said in his comment to your question, though -- if the other students haven't been loaded, you would have to query the database to check the count, which is something to keep in mind.

Comment: TNX @jjj ,I will try your IValidatableObject solution. I have no problem of adding reference to 'Room' from 'Student' as you comment. How will you do it then? . tnx.

Comment: @Dudi: Within `Student` you could add properties `public virtual Room Room { get; set; }` and/or `public int RoomID { get; set; }`. There's an example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx). Then you could use those properties to check the `Room`'s `Student` count.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jjj and everyone here that helped, that's how  I solve this issue
(based on the  IValidatableObject implementation):

The Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace College.Models
{
    public class Student : IValidatableObject
    {
        [Key]
        public int StudentID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual Room Room { get; set; }

        //validation:
        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {

            if (Room.Students.Count() > 20)
                yield return new ValidationResult("Too many students in class", new[] { "RoomId" });
        }


    }

public class Room
{
    public Room()
    {
        Students = new List<Student>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int RoomID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students {get;set;}

}

}
```

Controller:

```
// POST: Rooms/Edit/5
// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(Room room)
{
    try
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(room).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(post);

    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
    {
        var error = ex.EntityValidationErrors.First().ValidationErrors.First();
        this.ModelState.AddModelError(error.PropertyName, error.ErrorMessage);
        return View(room);
    }

}
```

View:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoomId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```