# How to constrain the size of an ICollection in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, constraints

I have a binary association: `VetAssistant [1..2] ------ * Surgery`. I would like to limit size of the `ICollection<VetAssistant>` responsible for the association. I woule like it to be in a range from 1 to 2. Is it possible by data annotations?

```
public class Surgery 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<VetAssitant> VetAssitants { get; set; }
}

[Table("VetAssistants")]
public class VetAssitant : Person 
{
    public DateTime Hired { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Surgery> Surgeries { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: There are only very ugly ways to achieve "counting" constraints in a SQL database. So what's EF meant to do if it finds more than 2 rows?

Comment: You could try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086342/constrain-the-number-of-child-entities-in-entity-framework